# Character isn't moving even tho he isn't touching any border?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, collision

Hey so I'm quite new to programming and am currently working on a project that is based on Pokemon with a tutorial from YouTube but got stuck on a problem that doesnt seem to dissapear. Basically if the character touches the red squares he shouldn't walk any further but now i can't move him at all even tho he isn't visibally touching anything. [**Here **](https://youtu.be/yP5DKzriqXA?si=Y8qvkngGWM9Skxz4&t=10479)is the YouTube tutorial I'm working with.
I sadly cant post images yet but just imagine a 2d topview webgame and a Character in front of a house that cant move and red squares that are temporarily there so i know where the barriers are.

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

let moving = true;

canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;

const collisionsMap = [];
for (let i = 0; i < collisions.length; i += 70) {
  collisionsMap.push(collisions.slice(i, 70 + i));
}

class Boundary {
  static width = 48;
  static height = 48;
  constructor({ position }) {
    this.position = position;
    this.width = 48;
    this.height = 48;
  }

  draw() {
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

const boundaries = [];
const offset = {
  x: -1175,
  y: -590,
};

collisionsMap.forEach((row, i) => {
  row.forEach((symbol, j) => {
    if (symbol === 1027 || symbol === 1028)
      boundaries.push(
        new Boundary({
          position: {
            x: j * Boundary.width + offset.x,
            y: i * Boundary.height + offset.y,
          },
        })
      );
  });
});
const image = new Image();
image.src = "./img/Lonely Island.png";

const playerDownImage = new Image();
playerDownImage.src = "./img/playerDown.png";

const playerUpImage = new Image();
playerUpImage.src = "./img/playerUp.png";

const playerLeftImage = new Image();
playerLeftImage.src = "./img/playerLeft.png";

const playerRightImage = new Image();
playerRightImage.src = "./img/playerRight.png";

class Sprite {
  constructor({ position, velocity, image, frames = { max: 1 } }) {
    this.position = position;
    this.image = image;
    this.frames = frames;
    this.image.onload = () => {
      this.width = this.image.width / this.frames.max;
      this.height = this.image.height;
    };
  }

  draw() {
    c.drawImage(
      this.image,
      0,
      0,
      this.image.width / this.frames.max,
      this.image.height,
      this.position.x,
      this.position.y,
      this.image.width / this.frames.max,
      this.image.height
    );
  }
}

const player = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: canvas.width / 2 - 192 / 4 / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2 - 30 / 2,
  },
  image: playerDownImage,
  frames: {
    max: 4,
  },
});

const background = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: offset.x,
    y: offset.y,
  },
  image: image,
});

const keys = {
  w: {
    pressed: false,
  },
  a: {
    pressed: false,
  },
  s: {
    pressed: false,
  },
  d: {
    pressed: false,
  },
};

const movables = [background, ...boundaries];

function animate() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  background.draw();
  boundaries.forEach((boundary) => {
    boundary.draw();
  });

  function rectangularCollision({ rectangle1, rectangle2 }) {
    return (
      rectangle1.position.x + rectangle1.width >= rectangle2.position.x &&
      rectangle1.position.x <= rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.width &&
      rectangle1.position.y <= rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.height &&
      rectangle1.position.y + rectangle1.height >= rectangle2.position.y
    );
  }

  movables.forEach((movable) => {
    if (rectangularCollision({ rectangle1: player, rectangle2: movable })) {
      console.log("Collision detected");
    }
  });

  player.draw();
}

animate();

if (keys.w.pressed && lastKey === "w") {
  player.animate = true;
  player.image = player.sprites.up;

  checkForCharacterCollision({
    characters,
    player,
    characterOffset: { x: 0, y: 3 },
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (
      rectangularCollision({
        rectangle1: player,
        rectangle2: {
          ...boundary,
          position: {
            x: boundary.position.x,
            y: boundary.position.y + 3,
          },
        },
      })
    ) {
      // moving = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (moving)
    movables.forEach((movable) => {
      movable.position.y += 3;
    });
} else if (keys.a.pressed && lastKey === "a") {
  player.animate = true;
  player.image = player.sprites.left;

  checkForCharacterCollision({
    characters,
    player,
    characterOffset: { x: 3, y: 0 },
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (
      rectangularCollision({
        rectangle1: player,
        rectangle2: {
          ...boundary,
          position: {
            x: boundary.position.x + 3,
            y: boundary.position.y,
          },
        },
      })
    ) {
      // moving = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (moving)
    movables.forEach((movable) => {
      movable.position.x += 3;
    });
} else if (keys.s.pressed && lastKey === "s") {
  player.animate = true;
  player.image = player.sprites.down;

  checkForCharacterCollision({
    characters,
    player,
    characterOffset: { x: 0, y: -3 },
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (
      rectangularCollision({
        rectangle1: player,
        rectangle2: {
          ...boundary,
          position: {
            x: boundary.position.x,
            y: boundary.position.y - 3,
          },
        },
      })
    ) {
      // moving = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (moving)
    movables.forEach((movable) => {
      movable.position.y -= 3;
    });
} else if (keys.d.pressed && lastKey === "d") {
  player.animate = true;
  player.image = player.sprites.right;

  checkForCharacterCollision({
    characters,
    player,
    characterOffset: { x: -3, y: 0 },
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (
      rectangularCollision({
        rectangle1: player,
        rectangle2: {
          ...boundary,
          position: {
            x: boundary.position.x - 3,
            y: boundary.position.y,
          },
        },
      })
    ) {
      // moving = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (moving)
    movables.forEach((movable) => {
      movable.position.x -= 3;
    });
}

let lastKey = "";

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w.pressed = true;
      lastKey = "w";
      break;

    case "a":
      keys.a.pressed = true;
      lastKey = "a";
      break;

    case "s":
      keys.s.pressed = true;
      lastKey = "s";
      break;

    case "d":
      keys.d.pressed = true;
      lastKey = "d";
      break;
  }
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "w":
      keys.w.pressed = false;
      break;

    case "a":
      keys.a.pressed = false;
      break;

    case "s":
      keys.s.pressed = false;
      break;

    case "d":
      keys.d.pressed = false;
      break;
  }
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log("Key down:", e.key);
  // Rest des Event-Listener-Codes
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  console.log("Key up:", e.key);
  // Rest des Event-Listener-Codes
});

// playerImage.onload = () => {
//   console.log("Player image loaded");
//   // Rest der onload-Funktion
// };
```

I tried to make the Character only move in the space that isn't red, basically just a simple barrier to keep the character on the island.

Comment: Can you not post the full implementation here? You can inject working HTML/CSS/JS into your post. It would be easier for people to help you. In any case, on a quick glance I see around line 152 `if (keys.w.pressed && lastKey === "w") { ...`, shouldn't this be wrapped in a function that runs on every key press (or polling iteration) ? This logic seems like it would only run once (on app mount).

Comment: @Yogi well that's a question I've been asking myself for the past 2 hours or so, I'm not that far yet but the character should still be able to move and the only thing I modified were the things I had to since I didn't use the Island he did but created my own.